# Push Notification for iOS device

Tags: java, ios, google-app-engine, apple-push-notifications, javapns

Can anyone help me in details how to send push notification for iOS device while I am using Java for server side program and I am using  Google App Engine.

Thanks.

Comment: this is a rather complicated process. go and check out ray wenderlich's tutorial if you don't know where to start http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 0):

First you must have access to [Sockets Java API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/), which requires you to enable billing.

Second, use the [java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) library. It needs [some modifications](http://googleappenginetutorial.blogspot.com/2013/04/java-apns-on-appengine.html) to run on AppEngine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will you please explain in more details because I am new in app engine and iOS as well, so if possible kindly mention server side code (Java) and all other required staff. Thanks

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works - you have to write your own code.